# Free offline alternative to Toodledo for Windows

Tags: windows, note-taking, contact-manager, todo

[Toodledo](https://www.toodledo.com) might be the best match for my task management needs; it has Tasks, Notes, List, … But there are some problems with it. It doesn't provide a desktop version and doesn't work offline.

I want these features:

- Working fine on Windows 7 and higher
- Being free or open source
- Supporting tasks
- Providing reminders
- Providing recurring tasks
- Providing categories (and subcategories perhaps)
- Providing notes (with sticking ability)
- Providing contacts (it's not necessary)
- Working fine when offline (I think this is the most important difference between Wunderlist and Microsoft To-Do)

I've already tried Wieldy, Task List Guru, Task Coach, Things, Wunderlist and Microsoft To-Do. I found Wunderlist the best one, but it's going to be discontinued and they stated that they stopped working on the Windows version already. It was somehow slow on Windows.

Comment: Have a look at [Trello](https://alternativeto.net/software/trello/).

Comment: @MSC Great suggestion. It provides a Windows app (not an installation) which doesn't work on older versions (for example Windows 7). And it doesn't work offline on Windows as they say. You need to add a Power-Up to enable recurring tasks: Menu > Power Ups > Card Repeater. I loved its Power-Up feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try my [Portable Kanban](https://dmitryivanov.net/). Disclosure: I'm developer of PK.

- It works offline.
- It's free, can be used commercially. Works on Windows only.
- It has a Pomodoro timer that is configurable (work/short pause/long pause intervals, sound).
- Has topics and tags, configurable views.
- Has a lot of options for configuring UI and board.
- May be used for teams too (requires Redis server).

Here's a screenshot of the task backlog:

[image: Portable Kanban]

Comment: I tried it, but I couldn't find recurring option. Some usual commands are hidden in the Settings which isn't good. I think you can make it much better.

Comment: Note: Development stopped in early 2018, the website closed around 7/2018 – so sadly this software is no longer available. @Dmitry if you're still around and have an updated link, please provide it.