# Offline ToDoist alternative

Tags: offline, task-management, todo

ToDoist alternative that works offline?

Don't get me wrong, I love ToDoist and its many features, but it doesn't actually work offline. You have to connect to the internet and login every time you load the app... which is fine until you lose connection for any given reason. I've spoken to the developers and they are very disinterested in making it work offline, and dismiss their users by telling them it works offline if you connect to the internet to login when you launch the app. Well, what happens when it crashes, when it closes, or when you restart and you don't have a connection? Bingo, you're locked out of your entire work life.

So I'm looking for a new to-do app.

At the bare minimum, it needs to have the following features

1. works fully offline. that means I can see and edit my tasks without needing to connect for any reason and they will be synced when a connection is made available. I can close the app and open it without being connected to the internet and still access and use it.
2. syncable. New tasks on Windows show up quickly on my Android and vice versa, or at most with an accessible manual refresh
3. there must be some way to quickly jot down a task with a keystroke, or some quick responsive window that can at least be pulled and hidden via an .ahk script or something like that. Todoist does this well with the win+alt+q keystroke. The window it brings up is exactly what I want.
4. Reminders or alarms for tasks.
5. recurring tasks (i.e. daily, weekly, monthly)
6. Native Windows 10 and Android compatible (not a web app since they don't work offline). Obviously, the more platforms the merrier, for lifetime compatibility, but I realize that is asking an arm and a leg, so W10 and Android are sufficient for now.

Thank you for any recommendations.

Comment: If I got this right, you're looking for a solution running on Android? Then a good starter would be my corresponding app listing: [Todo Lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo). As for sync: what should it sync with server-side? Tasks can be synced via CalDAV, so several calendar services would be possible, including self-hosted (Baïkal, Nextcloud, …). You can work entirely offline, and sync whenever a connection is available. I cannot tell much about the Windows part (I'm on Linux), but e.g. Thunderbirds calendar addon is AFAIK capable of the same CalDAV sync.

Comment: My bad, I should have specified that I'm mainly looking for a Windows app (compatible with W10) that also syncs to an equally offline-capable Android app. I'm not very interested in syncing it to a calendar of any kind, although that would be a bonus. Thanks for the resource list, I'm having a look.

Comment: I'm currently exploring VueMinder, MyLifeOrganized, and LeaderTask, as all seem to have the functionality I wanted, though they were harder to find, or some reason. Probably more product-focused than marketing-focused, is my guess, as their features and reliability so far appear above and beyond what ToDoist is capable of. TickTick looked promising but it just would not sync changes from the Windows 10 app, even manually, and this appears to be a common problem. I'm currently leaning toward VueMinder because its add task window is feature-rich.

Comment: Related. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/47009/246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on MyLifeOrganized for the time being. It is a paid solution but it supports everything I need. VueMinder was extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few possibilities, I settled on [TickTick](https://ticktick.com/).

This has apps for various OS, including Windows10 and Android that you request.  These work offline and sync on reconnection.

Tasks can be added in many ways, including via the likes of IFTTT and Zapier.  The sorting, notification and annotation options are more than enough for my needs.

Comment: TickTick has countless reports of sync issues with the Windows 10 client. It was the first thing that didn't work when I installed it. I would be careful recommending this one.

Comment: Interesting.  I've had sync issues with other apps but never with TickTick. Maybe just lucky.

Comment: Would have loved to have TickTick working! I would certainly recommend it if someone isn't experiencing sync issues.